# how can i display the result of two checkboxes in a label, which one is being checked or even both are being checked in a WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin, uwp

many thanks for your help.
I am totally a new guy in programming world, therefore I really need your hand!

Problem is:

i've two checkboxes and one label, by checking each single checkbox the label should display, which one is being checked. if both are being checked, label should display both are checked, but in two lines. if one is unchecked, should clear its own relevant sentence but not whole texts in the label.

MY XML:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Width="350">
            <CheckBox x:Name="CheckboxOne" 
                      Content="First Checkbox"
                      Checked="FirstCheckbox"
                      Unchecked="UncheckedOne"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="CheckboxTwo" 
                      Content="Second Checkbox"
                      Checked="SecondCheckbox"
                      Unchecked="UncheckedTwo"/>
            <Label Name="LabelText"
               Height="70"
               Grid.Column="1"/>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

MY C#

```
private void FirstCheckbox(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckboxOne.IsChecked == true)
    {
        LabelText.Content += "First checkbox is being checked";
    }

}
private void SecondCheckbox(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckboxTwo.IsChecked == true)
    {
        LabelText.Content += "Second checkbox is being checked";
    } 
}
private void UncheckedOne(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckboxOne.IsChecked == false)
    {
        LabelText.Content = "";
    }
}
private void UncheckedTwo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckboxTwo.IsChecked == false)
    {
        LabelText.Content = "";          
    }
}
```

one of my expectation should be so, in case, both are being checked!

First checkbox is being checked

Second checkbox is being checked

many thanks for your help!

Comment: what do you mean by two different sentences?

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply! I meant in two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code should do what you want:

```
    private void FirstCheckbox(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MakeLable();
    }
    private void SecondCheckbox(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MakeLable();
    }
    private void UncheckedOne(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MakeLable();
    }
    private void UncheckedTwo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MakeLable();
    }
    private void MakeLable()
    {
        if (CheckboxOne.IsChecked && CheckboxTwo.IsChecked)
        {
            LabelText.Content = $"First checkbox is being checked{Environment.NewLine}Second checkbox is being checked";
        }
        else if (CheckboxOne.IsChecked && !CheckboxTwo.IsChecked)
        {
            LabelText.Content = "First checkbox is being checked";
        }
        else if (!CheckboxOne.IsChecked && CheckboxTwo.IsChecked)
        {
            LabelText.Content = "Second checkbox is being checked";
        }
        else
        {
            LabelText.Content = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: many many thanks, first I had to write (==true) after each IsChecked property. now when both checkboxes are being checked, few spaces appear before first sentence. by the way, thanks really a lot!

Comment: you could thank me by voting my answe up and choosing it as answer ;)

Comment: ohhh haha! I am sorry! I didn't know it, I am a farmer man! I hope, I clicked the right icons :)